# Elasticsearch snapshot taking forever

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch has indices like `index_name-YYYYMM`. Data is continuously written to Elasticsearch and it’s in the order of 1TB per hour.

indexA-202102

indexB-202102

indexC-202102

.

.

.

I’m trying to take a snapshot everyday using python client. If I specify single index, snapshot completes in few seconds. But if I specify multiple indices, it’s taking forever as new data is being added continuously.

Is there a way we can solve this ?

```
def snapshot(self, repository, indices, snapshot_name):
     snap_settings = {'indices': indices, 'ignore_unavailable': True,
                      'include_global_state': True}
     return self.es_client.snapshot.create(repository=repository,
                                           snapshot=snapshot_name, 
                                           body=snap_settings)
```

Comment: After taking multiple indices snapshot (which is taking hours), can you share snapshot status details ? Does it contains any specific error or warning ? For command you can refer to documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-snapshot-status-api.html

Comment: this is the response `{
  "snapshots" : [ ]
}`

Comment: Empty snapshot response indicates that there are no snapshots that are running.
I don't see any issue with elasticsearch. The snapshot you have taken must have been completed. Correct me if snapshot didn't complete .

Comment: After the snapshot is complete, I am getting `{"snapshots" : [ ] }`. When snapshot is running I see status as STARTED and some more details on number of records to take snapshot of and number of records completed. Before the snapshot completes saving all record, the target record size is increasing as my tasks keep writing data.

Comment: Then its normal behavior. When you said "it’s taking forever" , I thought snapshot is stuck.